# SQL Server 2012 Connection Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012

I am running MS-SQL Server on Windows Server 2012.
From time to time I get this Exception:

> Server Exception : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=6; handshake=9410; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=1; [Post-Login] complete=5627; ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out at

When it happens I get hundreds of them in a few minutes and after a while it recovers.
I couldn't find anything useful on the web. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a multi-subnet availability group involved? If so, the AG could be failing over and it takes a while for the record in DNS to get updated...

Comment: Thanks @BenThul . there isn't any multi-subnet availability group involved. it is an IIS server approaching an SQL server on the same instance. no IP's involved. It that what you mean?

Comment: Well... nuts. I guess I would monitor CPU on the machine and see if spikes correlate to the times when you get these connection timeouts.

Comment: I've started had this a couple of times on servers with both IIS and SQL server. The most recent time was on a different machine. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421978/help-troubleshooting-sqlexception-timeout-expired-on-connection-in-a-non-load suggests memory use and swapping - in case that helps? My problem appears to be compounded by an Umbraco sute then taking 100% of the CPU forever :(